# How to make intervals of data after 6 rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, sklearn-pandas

Hi I have a scenario where I have to maintain a number after every 6 six row.

For example here is my dataframe

```
client_id   patient_id  Total Clinic   Clinic Number  
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6021        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    172         6137        1            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 1
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
    187         5658        5            Clinic 2
```

I want to achieve below results so that after every six rows index count will be updated

```
client_id  patient_id  Total Clinic  Clinic Number  Index_Number            
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6021        1            Clinic 1            1
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    172        6137        1            Clinic 1            2
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 1            3
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
    187        5658        5            Clinic 2            4
```

Need Help Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda hacky, but it works. Maybe there's a more straightforward way to do it.

```
df['Index_Number'] = np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[0]/6), 6)[:df.shape[0]]+1
```

Comment: Can we start number from 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a column of ones; compute cumulative sum and subtract 1 (to start from zero); and compute floordiv (i.e., integer division)

```
    df['Index'] = 1
    df['Index'] = df['Index'].cumsum() - 1
    df['Index'] = df['Index'].floordiv(6)
```

Comment: Its starting from 0